# Is the limit of integral of integrable functions finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My question arose when I was reading the monotone convergence theorem last night. I noticed that monotone convergence theorem actually indicates that $sup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\int|u_j|^pd\mu$ is not necessarily finite for an increasing sequence of integrable functions $(u_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$.

$\textbf{My Question}$

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. $(u_j)_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an sequence of integrable functions in $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$. Suppose that $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\int|u_j|^pd\mu=\int|u|^pd\mu$ for some measurable function $u$. Is it possible that $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\int|u_j|^pd\mu=\int|u|^pd\mu=\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consider $X = \Bbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue/Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesgue measure; also, let $p=1$. For each $j$, let $u_j = \chi_{[-j,j]}$, the characteristic function of $[-j,j]$. For each $j$, $u_j$ is clearly measurable and has finite integral, so it is integrable. Also, the sequence $\{u_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to the constant function $1$ (which is also measurable) as $j \to \infty$. The limit of the integrals however is $\infty$.

Comment: It's a wonderful example. Thanks!